# Fine Structure Degenerate Perturbation Theory Hydrogen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Note: We are dealing with perturbation on the states $|nlm_lm_s>$ where *n* is the principle quantum number, *l* is the angular momentum quantum number, and $m_l$ and $m_s$ are the eigenvalues of $L_z$ and $S_z$ corresponding to this particular eigenstate. *j* is the Total angular momentum quantum number: $j = l \pm 1/2 $.

In page 275 of Griffiths, he finishes the derivation of the energy perturbation due to the fine structure correction. He then says that the fine structure breaks degeneracy in *l* but not in *j*. Why is this? It seems to me that the degeneracy in *j* is broken, and that there is still degeneracy in *l*.

[image: Griffiths Text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my 1995 edition the text (on page 242) reads:

[image: 1995 edition]

So presumably this is an error in whatever edition you have.

Comment: Thanks. I would upvote, but I have not the reputation to do so.

Comment: @ZaneDufour: if this answers your question please click on the tick symbol to accept the answer.

Comment: Sadly, the 3rd edition (2018) reverted back to the error reported by @ZaneDufour